# Identify whether current SQL version belongs to Azure or Microsoft SQL server stand alone

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I want to know which version of SQL is connecting my application in c# on the bases of connection string plus any other method.

Basically user provides connection string in my application either it would connects to Microsoft SQL Server or Microsoft Azure SQL.

So, on that I want to run set of queries on the respective version.

Comment: Generally the connection string is controlled by the application, not the user. If the user is supplying the connection details, then shouldn't they know what they're connecting to, and thus know the limitations of the version; why does the application need to know?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @larnu, forgot to mention that it is at installation time....

Comment: Create a configuration setting in your application and get the user to define what version it is at configuration.

Comment: and get the OP define what version it is, what do you mean by OP?

Comment: "OP" = "[Original Poster](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/O/op_original_poster.html)". That's you .

Comment: I corrected to user (before the OP (really OP) asked that), @UweKeim . So the person installing the application would be asked "What version of SQL Server are you using", with a list of **supported** versions. They would select the appropriate one and the application now knows what version it's installing against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@@VERSION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/version-transact-sql-configuration-functions?view=sql-server-2017) will tell you that. It will return text starting with `Microsoft SQL Azure` if you are connected to Azure.

```
select @@VERSION
```

> **Azure**
>
> Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Nov 20 2018 21:01:54   Copyright (C) 2018 Microsoft Corporation
>
> **On premise**
>
> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB4458842) - 13.0.4224.16 (X64)   Aug 18 2018 09:00:06   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 6.3  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

You can also check the server name from the connection string - does it ends with `.database.secure.windows.net` or `.database.windows.net`.

Answer (score 4):

Although `@@version` seems like a way to go, parsing such a string might be tricky. The [current documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) recommends this approach:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition');
```

> To programmatically determine the engine edition, use SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition'). This query will return '5' for standalone databases and '8' for managed instances in Azure SQL Database.

Comment: And, if you'd prefer to have the text 'translated' for you (instead of playing 'magic numbers' with the Edition IDs), you can simply run: SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Edition'); instead.

Comment: @MichaelK.Campbell, depends on what you're after. `Edition` displays a human-readable string, the actual edition. However, `EngineEdition` groups them together by functionality. For example, Enterprise, Developer and Evaluation have the same functionality, so they have the same value `3`. In scripts, the latter is easier to check, as scripts tend not to be concerned with licensing, only what you can and cannot do on a particular instance (online index rebuild, some AG bits which are Enterprise-only, etc.).